# Can an .ssh/config Host have multiple HostName entries?

Tags: ssh

I've setup ssh and router port forwarding so I can ssh into a computer on my home network when I'm not at home. Currently I have two entries in my `.ssh/config` file one for when I'm on my home network and one for when I'm not:

```
Host mycomputer
  HostName 192.168.X.X

Host mycomputerathome
  HostName my.no-ip.dynamic
```

This works but I'm wondering if I can make things easier on myself. I was hoping there's a way to list multiple HostName entries such that if the first fails it falls back to the second:

```
Host mycomputer
  HostName 192.168.X.X
  HostName my.no-ip.dynamic
```

So that it will first try to connect to a host on my local network and if that isn't present, it'll try to connect using my no-ip dynamic host name. I have tried entering two HostNames but running `ssh mycomputer` just blocks doing nothing.

I've turned off password authentication in favor of keys so accidentally connecting to a computer on the local network when I'm not on my home network shouldn't risk my password going anywhere it shouldn't.

Is it possible to specify fallback HostNames to try if the first one doesn't work?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424755/how-to-set-ssh-to-try-not-only-port-22-but-secondary-port-every-time/424826#424826 is similar and probably can be adapted for hostname instead of port

Comment: BTW, the `.ssh/config` can run scripts for certain properties. I know you can with ProxyCommand. You could do something as shown in this Q&A from SF - https://serverfault.com/questions/401233/how-to-specify-multiple-hostname-port-combinations-in-ssh-config.

Comment: [SSH wrapper that tries several connection parameters](https://superuser.com/q/1249358/432690).

Answer (score 13):

It's ugly, but I think you *could* do it using the `exec` criterion to `Match` on the exit status of a port knock e.g.

```
Host mycomputer
  Match exec "nc -z 192.168.1.11 %p"
    HostName 192.168.1.11
  Match !exec "nc -z 192.168.1.11 %p"
    HostName my.no-ip.dynamic
```

Note that this can't really tell whether you're on "your" home network - just that you're on a private LAN segment with the same address range that happens to have a service listening on the same address/port.

Comment: I did have to add a `-w 1` or else `nc` seemed to wait forever. What could be simpler is the second Match can `Match exec "true"` because if the first match failed, just blindly try the second choice.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn ah yes I was trying to think of a nicer way to do the alternate condition (pity `Match` doesn't have an `Else`)

Comment: So I ran into an issue with this approach. I also run a site, say xyz.com, and when I tried to `ssh xyz.com` my `Match exec "true"` caught that and redirected me into my home server using my remote HostName. I will try with your exec but I think the same thing will happen.

Comment: Yeah, using your `Match exec... Match !exec` is causing ssh'ing to other domains to trigger the `Match !exec` and rewrite the HostName.

Comment: So it turns out that `~/.ssh/config` couldn't care less about indentation. Certain commands reset the scope, i.e. each new Host line says "previous lines were for the previous Host, the following lines are for this new Host." Turns out `Match` has the same "scope resetting" power as Host. To account for this, I replaced my Host line with `Match Host mycomputer exec "nc -w 1 -z 192.168.X.X 22"` and defined all the custom values for my local network. I then added a matching line except `!exec` and added all the values for when I'm off network. Now it works fine for all hosts.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using like this.

```
Match host mycomputer exec "nc -w 1 -z 192.168.1.11 %p"
    HostName 192.168.1.11
Match host mycomputer # fallback
    HostName my.no-ip.dynamic
Host mycomputer
    # ... other configs

Host not-my-computer
# ... other configs
```

ssh_config doesn't have something like indentation block. If you want to limit match sentence to a specific host, then you should describe the full condition.

You can avoid long awaiting `nc` by giving it `-w 1` (connection timeout 1s) option, and you can utilize following behaviour to avoid multiple invocation of `nc`

> Match
> Introduces    a conditional block.  If all of the criteria on the
> Match line    are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines
> override those set    in the global section of the config file,
> until either another Match    line or the end of the file.  If a
> keyword appears in    multiple Match blocks that are satisfied, only
> the first instance    of the keyword is applied.

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)

Comment: I don't know what `ssh` and `nc` you are using, but on Ubuntu, comments are allowed in `.ssh/config` *only* on their own line, and `nc -G` isn't; it's `nc -w`.

Comment: I prefer passive checks e.g. `nmcli d show|grep`, `ip -o addr`etc, they are much faster; for virtual network ping maybe more preferable since it support specifying outgoing interface `ping -I docker0 172.17.0.1` which fails instantly if the interface is not up.

Answer (score 4):

No; if you specify multiple `HostName`s for one `Host` entry, only the first will be acknowledged:

```
$ grep -A5 Host .ssh/config
Host test
   HostName fake.tld.xyzzy
   HostName real.example.com
   HostName 127.1.2.3
   User username
$ ssh test
ssh: Could not resolve hostname fake.tld.xyzzy: Name or service not known
```

Comment: I guess it makes sense. If I type in `ssh mycomputer` it should be pretty unambiguous which computer I'm connecting to.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a GREAT question, I always wondered too.**

The short answer is No.. You cannot. So I decided to do it myself.

You can use a simple script to get the the desired functionality.

**I wrote a [Github Pages post for this](https://awbmilne.github.io/blog/SSH-Host-Fallback/)**

---

### TLDR

On UNIX Try this:
(*On Windows, read my [Github Pages Post](https://awbmilne.github.io/blog/SSH-Host-Fallback/)*)

**~/.ssh/scripts/check-host-fingerprint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

fingerprints=$(ssh-keygen -lf <(ssh-keyscan $1 2>/dev/null))

for fingerprint in $fingerprints
do
        if [ "$fingerprint" == "$2" ]
        then
                exit 0
        fi
done

exit 1
```

**~/.ssh/config**

```
# Host with Global Fallback
Match host "my_auto_host" exec "/bin/bash %d/.ssh/scripts/check-host-fingerprint.sh 192.168.0.100 SHA256:12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567"
    Hostname 192.168.0.100
    Port 22
Host my_auto_host
    User username
    Hostname server.domain.org
    Port 1022

# Secondary Host using Primary as Proxy
Host secondary
    User u5ernam3
    Hostname 192.168.0.101
    Port 22
    ProxyJump my_auto_host
```

If this doesnt work for you, Please read my **[Github Pages post](https://awbmilne.github.io/blog/SSH-Host-Fallback/)**.
It it still doesn't work, feel free to contact me by email (can find on blog sidebar/footer).

Answer (score 1):

```
crontab:
@reboot ~/.ssh/scripts/distant_check.sh

~/.ssh/scripts/distant_check.sh :
ping -c1 [local_server_ip]
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then 
cp ~/.ssh/config_local ~/.ssh/config
else
cp ~/.ssh/config_distant ~/.ssh/config
fi
```

Comment: Can you perhaps [edit] your question, and add a little explanation of how this answers the original question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ProxyCommand to run a script to try addresses in turn.  For example:

```
Host mycomputer
  ProxyCommand sh -c "for h in 192.168.x.x my.no-ip.dynamic; do if socat stdio TCP:\$h:%p,connect-timeout=1; then break; fi; done"
```

I do this and also similar tricks with link-local IPv6 addresses to find devices.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @steeldriver and @seongchan-lee,

```
Host mycomputer
  Match exec "nc -w 1 -z 192.168.1.11 %p"
  HostName 192.168.1.11
  Match exec "nc -w 1 -z my.no-ip.dynamic %p"
  HostName my.no-ip.dynamic
  User corey
```